# BMW E46 2002 Check Control and Radiator is lighting on Dashboard

Tags: bmw, headlight, radiator, dashboard

Yesterday I removed Angel Eyes and after that when I started up the engine there was Check Control front lights warning. How can I reset this warning? There also is radiator warning and this light appears sometimes when I first start car in the morning and after 2 min it disappears. Is there coolant level problem for radiator warning?

[image]

Comment: You realize there is more than one light at the location of where the indicator is shown? IOW, your headlight may be good, but one of the other indicator bulbs which is located on that corner of the vehicle may be out. You need to check all of them for function before you think there is an issue with the OBDII system or your dashboard.

Comment: Also, if you have halos on an e46, then you have aftermarket headlights. Is the car coded for xenon bulbs? If not they'll show as burned out until you turn them on.